# Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1913 (note 1 of 3)

Tags: identificación-de-término

For the year 1913 in my Great Grandfathers Civil Guard records there are three entries.

Here is the first one:
[image]

This is the transcribed text so far:

> En 3 de Abril año marginal xxx este individuo xxx hado a Rio
> Ginito (?) “xxxdra” con objeto de prestan el servicio de concentración
> con motiva (?) de la xxgar que en dicho xxx xxx mineral, de donde
> requiso el 14 del mismo que en incorporó a puesto.
>
> El 2o Jefe

This bit **Rio Ginito (?) “xxxdra”** seems like it might actually be **Rio Cristol "Hendra"**. But I can't find such a term.

---

### Translation

Here is the translation:

> On the 3rd of April this individual went to Rio Tinto "Huelva" to
> provide the concentration service on the occasion of the strike that
> the miners held in that area, from where he returned on the 14th of
> the same month when he returned to his post.
>
> The 2nd Chief

DeepL does offer **marshalling** as an alternative to **concentation**. Previously I added **crowd control duties** in parenthesis. Thoughts?

---

### Related Questions

- [Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1913 (note 2 of 3)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39464/28260)

Comment: I have updated my answer in relation with your doubt about concentration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have read *Rio Cristol "Hendra"* and now I'm impelled to answer.

[**Río Tinto**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%ADo_Tinto) (Red River) is a river located in the province of **Huelva** in Andalucía, Spain. The river gives its name to a [nearby mining town](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minas_de_Riotinto). The mining company, [Rio Tinto Company Limited](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rio_Tinto_Company_Limited), was owned by Englishmen.

> En 3 de Abril año marginal **marchó** este individuo **concentrado**? a **[Río Tinto "Huelva"](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minas_de_Riotinto)** con objeto de **prestar** el servicio de concentración con
> **motivo** de la **huelga** que en **dicha zona sostuvieron los mineros**, de donde **regresó**
> el 14 del mismo que **se** incorporó a **su** puesto.
>
> El 2º Jefe

More information (in Spanish) about various strikes in Rio Tinto (including the aforementioned one) [here](https://www.huelvainformacion.es/provincia/Riotinto-periodo-huelgas_0_709129405.html)

[image: Rio Tinto around that date (can't find the exact year)]

---

You can translate concentración as **concentration**. Both words have the exact same meaning in Spanish and English, according to the DLE and the Oxford Dictionary respectively

> [concentración](https://dle.rae.es/concentraci%C3%B3n) (noun)
>
> 1. f. Acción y efecto de concentrar o concentrarse.
>
> [concentrar](https://dle.rae.es/concentrar) (verb, to gather)
> 2. tr. Congregar un número generalmente grande de personas para que patenticen una actitud determinada
>
> [concentration](https://www.lexico.com/definition/concentration) (noun)
> 2. A close gathering of people or things.

Due to the historical context we can assume that **servicio de concentración** is just an euphemism for **control de masas** ([crowd-control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crowd_control)).

In the following images, you can see the Guardia Civil doing this kind of service in Barcelona, in [1902](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_carga) (painted by Ramón Casas) and 1909 respectively. It's not hard to imagine what they did in Rio Tinto in 1913.

[image: The Charge by Ramón Casas]

[image: Semana trágica Barcelona 1909]

Comment: Fascinating! I am at work now (twilight shift). You have given me many links to review. Thanks for your hard work! I will check it all out tomorrow afternoon and work on the translation based on this.

Comment: I still have more reading to do ... :) I used Google Translate to translate the webpages but then it would not let me print the complete translated article. I see others have had the same problem.

Comment: Thank you for that addition refinement!

Comment: I have found a way to print to PDF when I use Google Translate of a web link. But I have to select the text first. Then uf I print on the MacBook Pro it lets me print a properly formatted PDF.

Comment: Side point: It is interesting to note that my late grandfather was born in February 1913. I admit that I find it interesting that his papers don't actually mention his next of kin (just his mum and dad).

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Our parent's names are still present today in our DNI, the National Identification Document. I can see no reasons for children to be listed in military records.

Comment: When I said "next of kin" I was referring to his wife. And ask regards this DNI, I am not sure about that, but it is another subject. :)

Comment: @AndrewTruckle But you mentioned your grandparent being born in 1913 in the same comment. That got me confused.

Comment: When I wrote "(just his mum and had)" I was referring to the fact that his parent, my great-great-grandparents, were at-least mentioned by name on the first page, but not his wife (next of kin). On the English military papers for my Great Grandfather it does mention my great-grandmother.  And on other papers of other indirect ancestors it mentions all the male children, But I admit they lack all the history that we are gleaning here for my great-grandfather.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I see it now. But the whole comment was in the context of my great-grandfather. He had a child (my grandfather) in 1913 .... That woukld mave been clearer.