# Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1913 (note 2 of 3)

Tags: identificación-de-término

For the year 1913 in my Great Grandfathers Civil Guard records there are three entries.

Here is the second one:

[image]

This is the transcribed text so far:

> El Excmo. Sr. (Señor) Capitán Gral. (General) de la 2º Región en 31 de
> Mayo año del margen, tuvo a xxx a este individual del xxx al xxx a por
> interno para Osuna de este xxx xxx xxx xxx a mar en 15 Junio siguiente
> y terminé el 14 Agosto que sa xxx a su puesto.
>
> El 2º Jefe

I am beginning to find it easier to pick out certain words, like **Excmo.** or **Sr.** But still get stuck.

---

### Side Note

I know that I said there is three entries but it turns out the third one is a single sentence that looks much like the others for content. So I will not ask a question for the third note for 1913.

---

### Related Questions

- [Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1913 (note 1 of 3)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39458/28260)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest

> El Excmo. Sr. [Señor] Capitán Gral. [General] de la 2º Región en 31 de Mayo año del margen, tuvo a **bien conceder** a este **individuo** **dos meses de licencia por enfermo** para Osuna de **esta provᵃ [provincia]?** **los cuales empezó a usar** en 15 Junio siguiente y terminó el 14 Agosto que se incorporó a su puesto.
>
> El 2º Jefe

The word "**provᵃ**" is kind of a long shot, but nothing better comes to mind.

#### Translation:

- On May 31 of the year indicated in the margin, His Excellency Mr. Captain General of the Second Region saw fit to grant this individual two months of sick leave for Osuna in this province, which he started to use on the following June 15 and finished on August 14, when he returned to his post.

Comment: Thanks for yor answer and translation!

Comment: My late grandfather was born in the February of 1913. We don't know the nature of my great-grandfathers illness but it must have been nice for him to be at home for this time. I doubt they had **paternity leave** back in 1913!

Comment: @AndrewTruckle seems unlikely, yes... Maybe an injury? Nice that you are learning so much about your family's history!

Comment: Yes! Learning so much about my great-grandfather. Next is 1914 notes so let’s see what else comes up!